# Call PHP function within <embed> tag

Tags: php, html, video, youtube, embed

What I'm trying to do is take a YouTube playlist (http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLzMZz3zuUATIdU0RIndFQiQQzADew0hZq&index= RANDOM NUMBER), and call the random number inside an  tag.

This is the code so far:

```
<?php
$min=1;  $max=4;
$z = init rand(1, 4)
?>
<object width="375" height="100"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLzMZz3zuUATIdU0RIndFQiQQzADew0hZq"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="375" height="100" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLzMZz3zuUATIdU0RIndFQiQQzADew0hZq&index=<? $z ?>"></embed></object>
<?php
$min=1;  $max=4;
$z = init rand(1, 4)
?>
```

Where you see the link followed by `index=` is where I would like to place the random number.
Therefor, if the random number is `4`, then the index should end up as `<embed... ...hZq&index=4"></embed>`

I cannot find my way through this code. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing your echo statement (and depending on your setup, you complete opening PHP tag):

```
<? $z ?>
```

should be:

```
<? echo $z ?> or <?php echo $z ?>
```

or, if you have short tags enabled or are using PHP 5.4+:

```
<?= $z ?>
```